# How to write regex to match a specific pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to identify folder by its name.

Need a regular expression that should match this pattern " **- (any digit) -** ".

*So space dash space bracket any digit bracket close dash space*

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@" - (\d) -");
Match match = regex.Match("Folder Name - (0) - description");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

List of Folders:-

> 1. Folder A - (0) - expense
> 2. Folder A - (0) - Bills
> 3. Folder B - 1 - Daily wages
> 4. Folder C - Misc
> 5. Folder D - (100) - Library

Regex should match 1, 2, and 5

Comment: While it was a simple solution, why was this downvoted? It's a specific question, an attempt to solve it was shown, and there was a good list of sample data to match. Maybe it's just because I'm absolutely awful at regex myself but this seems fairly reasonable. If one is relatively new to regex it might not be obvious you need to escape parenthesis, when the character for matching ranges such as `[a-z]` is in brackets and not parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to escape `(` and `)` as they have a special meaning of defining a group:

```
@" - \(\d+\) -"
```

Also added repetition to the digit as you seem to need numbers according to example #5.